# How can I make my prompt show the current directory and the previous directory

Tags: command-line, bash

I edited the `.bashrc` file

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;36m\]\W:\[\033[01;34m\]\W \[\033[00m\]\$ '


else
    PS1='[${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u:\W \$ ] '
fi
```

so my prompt looks like this `user:Pictures:Pictures $`

but I want after my username to show my previous directory.

I know that with the command `basename $(dirname 'pwd')` I can extract the previous directory.

Is there any way I can use it so my prompt looks like this ?

`user:prevDir:Pictures $`

thank you very much (and sorry if my English or terminology isn't very good I am new to Ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

Replace the first `\W` with `${OLDPWD/\/home\/$USER/\~}`:

```bsh
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;36m\]${OLDPWD/\/home\/$USER/\~}:\[\033[01;34m\]\W \[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

```bsh
~$ cd tmp
~/tmp$ PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;36m\]${OLDPWD/\/home\/user/\~}:\[\033[01;34m\]\W \[\033[00m\]\$ '
user:~:tmp $
```

`${OLDPWD/\/home\/$USER/\~}` is a parameter expansion which replaces a potential expansion of `/home/$USER` at the start of `$OLDPWD` with `~`, in order to print `~` instead of the user's home directory's full path (miming the behavior of the default prompt).

If that's undesired, replace `\W` with just `$OLDPWD`:

```bsh
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;36m\]$OLDPWD:\[\033[01;34m\]\W \[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

```bsh
~$ cd tmp
~/tmp$ PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;36m\]$OLDPWD:\[\033[01;34m\]\W \[\033[00m\]\$ '
user:/home/user:tmp $
```

Comment: thank you man you were very helpfull and that worked perfectly .
The only problem I have is that I wanted if it's possible to have only the last directory .`(user:user:tmp and not user:/home/user:tmp)` .
Using this command on terminal `basename $(dirname 'pwd')`i get what i want but i cannot find a way to use it inside `bashrc` file .Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @user2913267 Do you mean something like this? `PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;36m\]$(basename "$OLDPWD"):\[\033[01;34m\]\W \[\033[00m\]\$ '`.